# Having trouble with Built-in Exception: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python-3.x, tdd

Having trouble with Built-in Exception: ModuleNotFoundError. I see nothing wrong with this solution, but am getting an Error. Checked out the docs but couldn't figure it out

folder structure

```
app
  __init__.py
  logic.py
test
  __init__.py
  test_logic.py
```

this error comes when i try to run the file from the command line directly --python test/test_logic.py

```
(tdd) D:\code\Outcome-15>coverage run test/test_logic.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test/test_logic.py", line 3, in <module>
        from app.logic import FizzBuzz
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

logic.py

`class FizzBuzz:
    def fizz_buzz_service(self, num):
        number_types = (int, float, complex)
        if isinstance(num, number_types):
            if num % 5 == 0 and num % 3 == 0:
                return 'FizzBuzz'
            elif num % 5 == 0:
                return 'Buzz'
            elif num % 3 == 0:
                return 'Fizz'
            else:
                return num
        else:
            raise ValueError`

test_logic.py

```
import unittest

from app.logic import FizzBuzz


class FizzBuzzServiceTestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    docstring for FizzBuzzServiceTestCases goes here!
    """

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Create an instance of fizz_buzz_service
        """

        self.fizzbuzz = FizzBuzz()

    def test_it_returns_a_number(self):
        """
        Test for the default behavior of returning a number if not divisible by 3, 5 or both
        """
        self.assertEqual(7, self.fizzbuzz.fizz_buzz_service(7))

    def test_should_return_Fizz(self):
        self.assertEqual("Fizz", self.fizzbuzz.fizz_buzz_service(3))

    def test_should_return_Buzz(self):
        self.assertEqual('Buzz', self.fizzbuzz.fizz_buzz_service(5))

    def test_should_return_FizzBuzz(self):
        self.assertEqual('FizzBuzz', self.fizzbuzz.fizz_buzz_service(15))

    def test_should_return_error_message_if_arg_not_number(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            self.fizzbuzz.fizz_buzz_service('five')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Your app directory should have a `__init__.py` to act as a module

Comment: both the directories have it

Comment: I asked for `app` directory. I don;t think your init in files have any difference here